# Unsetting PHP session variable doesnt display error message

Tags: php, session, unset

I am trying to display an error message when there is a username-password mismatch. I set a php session variable if username and password dont match. Then i header back to the same page, with an if conditioned php statement to display an error if the variable is set. But when i unset the variable after error display, there is no error displayed on the page.

I have seen similar problems mentioned in this forum. But i seem to be doing everything right as suggested in questions.. Please help me out...

This is part of my code flow...

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
.
.
if ($result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $_SESSION['admin_user'] = $result['id'];
            header('Location: admin_user.php');
        } else {
            $_SESSION['user_found'] = 0;
            header('Location: index.php');
        }
.
.
//in html body
<?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_found'])){
        if($_SESSION['user_found'] == 0){
?>  
    <div>
    <p class = "bg-danger text-danger">Username Password Mismatch</p>
    </div>

<?php   
unset($_SESSION['user_found']);
        } 
    }

?>
```

Now, if unset is removed..it works fine. If it is there, there is no display of error message.

Comment: what is the `$_SESSION['user_found']` value ?

Comment: @CodingCracker if i comment the unset() and echo, it gives the right value of 0 for $_SESSION['user_found']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not reloading the same page.. remove the header redirect.

```
if ($result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $_SESSION['admin_user'] = $result['id'];
            header('Location: admin_user.php');
        } else {
            $_SESSION['user_found'] = 0;
            //header('Location: index.php');
        }
```

Comment: Yes.. After this change, code works fine.. But can you tell why it didnt work earlier.

Comment: When the page is loaded once, it unsets your variable.. If by some case your page loads again, the variable is already unset and hence you can see no warning.. this could be something happening in the code you've not mentioned..

Answer (score 0):

When I tried the your code, things seem to work fine. Something should be wrong with the code you've not mentioned here..

To troubleshoot the problem instead of

```
unset($_SESSION['user_found']);
```

try changing the value of the variable.. say

```
$_SESSION['user_found'] = -1;
```

Comment: I tried changing the code as you suggested.. It still doesnt display an error. If i comment that line of code.. It displays the message..
The code i havent put here only contains html and part of mysql exchange.. mysql qrks fine because once user authentication i am able to redirect and access the session variable set for it..